# Why does gcc by default link crtbegin.o and crtend.o to every compiled executable

Tags: c, gcc, ld, libc

In an effort to understand the in's and out's of a POSIX libc implementation I have been making my own for the past year or so now by nibbling at the edges of the Single Unix Specification implementing function I believed to be within my skillset while trying to map out a plan on moving forward and I've come to the point where the next step is to create a runtime library.

Now I am trying to understand the logic behind how programs are linked to the c runtime library.

Reading what the gcc manual said about the initialization as well as the elf format text and some texted on embedded systems I've basically learned that the initialization code goes into it's own section .init and .fini, that the crti.o and crtn.o normally contain function stubs that are crtbegin and crtend flesh out by calling a series of functions specified in a list of function pointers that a linker script is supposed to define.

This leads me to my questions assuming that my summarization above is correct what is the logic behind designing the init and fini functions in such a way specifically in the way described below:

> The prologue of a function (__init) appears in the .init section of crti.o; the epilogue appears in crtn.o. Likewise for the function __fini in the .fini section. Normally these files are provided by the operating system or by the GNU C library, but are provided by GCC for a few targets. The objects crtbegin.o and crtend.o are (for most targets) compiled from crtstuff.c. They contain, among other things, code fragments within the .init and .fini sections that branch to routines in the .text section. The linker will pull all parts of a section together, which results in a complete __init function that invokes the routines we need at startup.

Why wouldn't the library init and fini functions just directly call the library initialization and destruction functions directly instead of listing them in a linker script and spreading bits of the section across several object files?

Also where do the functions that would be listed in the linker list come from. From the quote referenced below I am assuming that these function are specific to the crt to say associate std[in,out,err] file descriptors with the file streams or initialate the locale_t variable to C locale etc, if that is the case where these functions stored.

> The linker must build two lists of these functions—a list of initialization functions, called **CTOR_LIST**, and a list of termination functions, called **DTOR_LIST**.

Comment: The C standard begins at `main()` and ends at `exit()` (or any of the various equivalents). All the things that need to happen before `main()` and after `exit()` are implementation details that the standard doesn't specify, or care about. Those details depend on the system that the code is running on, and there are many different systems that GCC supports. Once you've ported *your* implementation to 16 different systems, you'll start to understand the problem that CTOR_LIST and DTOR_LIST are intended to solve, and you may or may not agree that those lists are a good solution.

Comment: I do not mean to sound like I am judging at how things are implemented as is I just don't understand the reasoning

Answer (score 0):

> Why wouldn't the library init and fini functions just directly call the library initialization and destruction functions directly instead of listing them in a linker script and spreading bits of the section across several object files?

They can't call the functions directly because they don't know the functions to call. In order to know that, they'd have to be generated at link time, which is essentially what they are: generated by the linker concatenating same-named sections.

However, all of this is, or at least should be, irrelevant legacy nonsense. For decades, `.{init,fini}_array` sections with `__{init,fini}_array_{start,end}` symbols or `DT_{INIT,FINI}_ARRAY` `_DYNAMIC` tags pointing into them, iterated by code provided in libc/ldso, has been the right way to do ctors/dtors. But the GCC start files (`crt{begin,end}*.o`) still exist to do messy, largely wrong stuff for initializing their (removed) Java runtime, transactional memory library, unwind tables, etc.

Comment: Wait are the CTOR and DTOR functions that are called by __init / __fini part internal to the libc to initialize the c library or are the functions a link time list of start and end routines for all libraries the linker is linking against?

Comment: `_init` and `_fini` aren't used for ctors/dtors anymore. Instead the `.init_array` and `.fini_array` sections are iterated by code. They each contain an array of function pointers for ctors/dtors to execute.

Comment: What are __init and __fini used for or are they vestigial functions?

Comment: They still get some fragments from GCC's start files (`crt{begin,end}*.o`) for calling into Java runtime init, transactional memory emulation init, unwind init, etc. and for calling the *legacy `__do_global_[cd]tors_aux` functions, but these functions iterate the old `.ctors`/`.dtors` arrays that aren't used with modern tooling. The iteration of `.init_array`/`.fini_array` is elsewhere.

Comment: By any chance can you suggest some further reading on this topic? I am interested to learn but hesitate to just dig into the glibc / gcc source code for legal reasons, I do not want to accidentally plagiarize gpl code as I plan on eventually releasing a product under a simpler license.